# Redirect Wordpress blog posts from one domain to another

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a wordpress blog: http://domadis.com and I want redirect all my blog posts and pages to http://wannabits.com using Redirect 301 in htaccess. But, I want to redirect only the posts and pages. I wanna continue using domadis.com for other kind of content.

I mean, I want all my old posts redirects to corresponding new posts in wannabits. Create a new blog in domadis.com and start to posting new posts.

I tried the code below (in htaccess) for all posts but it doesn´t worked.

```
Redirect 301 http://domadis.com/all-post/ http://wannabits.com/all-post/
```

Now I`m using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.COM/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works, but also redirect domadis.com to wannabits.com and I don`t want to do that.

Somebody can help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach using Wordpress hooks:

```
add_action('template_redirect', function() {
    // your conditions
    if(is_single() || is_page()) {
         wp_redirect("http://example.com/", 301);
    }
});
```

You can use above code in `functions.php`